# facebook open graph not making sense

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, facebook-opengraph

ok so this is the page I'm working on...

http://eventspeak.com/event-marketing-jobs/view/nightlife-brand-ambassador/

The issue is that when you click the share button, the image and og data isn't what's in the header.

This means that it's grabbing this info from somewhere else, and this other place takes precedence over what I can see in the header...

I've having a hard time finding where exactly those are being defined...

The result I'm after is the ability to define exactly what title, description, image...etc is used when the share button on that page is clicked.

To save some time, here is the header FILE:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://eventspeak.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/eslogo11-e13411803243961.png" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
```

Can't copy-paste what the console says, although notice how the og:image link isn't being used when the share button is clicked. The og:image is placed in manually by me in the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Facebook used caching and is displaying the old image. Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to debug your opengraph data.